# Overlay rug plots on line plot based on a secondary variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a simple basic working example of some line plots.

I'd like to add **rug plots** to the x-axis of this visualisation. However, the rug plots should be based on a separate *cluster_mass* variable (which indicates where there are significant clusters in the data); in other words, only present where !is.na(cluster_mass). Additionally, the degree of shading/color of the rug plots should be based on the size of the *cluster_mass*. Does anyone know how to do this? I wonder if it might be a bit convoluted because of the facetting, so some facetting is included here.

```
df <- data.frame("Condition" = c("Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender"),
             "Agreement" = c("Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement", "Non-Agreement"),
             "Time" = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18),
             "Mean_Amplitude" = c(1.76, 1.78, 1.80, 1.83, 1.87, 1.75, 1.56, 1.65, 1.7, 1.9, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.85, 1.73, 1.85, 1.65, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.76, 1.78, 1.80, 1.83, 1.87, 1.75, 1.56, 1.65, 1.7, 1.9, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.85, 1.73, 1.85, 1.65, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8),
             "Group" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
             "Language" = c("X", "X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X","X"),
             "cluster_mass" = c(NA, NA, NA, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2,NA, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2,NA, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2,NA, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2, 141.2,NA, 1000, 1000))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Mean_Amplitude, color = Agreement, linetype = Agreement, size = Agreement)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Non-Agreement" = "red", "Agreement" = "blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Non-Agreement" = "solid", "Agreement" = "solid")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("Non-Agreement" = 0.4, "Agreement" = 0.6)) +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~Group*Language, ncol = 2, labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line = FALSE)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(x = "Time (ms)", y = expression(paste("Amplitude (", mu, "V)"))) +
   theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Mean_Amplitude, 
             color = Agreement, linewidth = Agreement)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rug(aes(x = ifelse(is.na(cluster_mass), NA, Time), alpha = cluster_mass), 
           sides = "b", na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Non-Agreement" = "red", Agreement = "blue")) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(values = c("Non-Agreement" = 0.4, Agreement = 0.6)) +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~Group*Language, ncol = 2, 
             labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line = FALSE)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(x = "Time (ms)", y = expression(paste("Amplitude (", mu, "V)"))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: If I additionally wanted to vary the length/height of the rug plots based on say 1/p.cluster_mass, how can one do this? I'm having trouble with multiple size specifications. :-\

Comment: You could add something like `length = unit(2000/df$cluster_mass, "mm")` inside `geom_rug`